Getting mean coordinates for unique values in large dataset for hierarchical cluster analysis using QGIS
I'm trying to analyse two different groups (species) of animals in the same space that were fitted with GPS collars, to see how the groups interact within their own groups and with the other group.
I am trying to do a cluster analysis (Hierarchical, I think?) to first: see if there is any clustering within each group a and in group b. And then also to see if any clustering occurs between groups a and b.
I have a large dataset (1,000,000+ rows) of unique names with different numbers of rows of GPS data (lat and long) for each unique name. Each unique name belongs to either group a or b.
Can I use QGIS to get the mean coordinates for each unique name in this dataset?
I am a beginner in QGIS and big data.
